# How to add JSON data from server to CoreData db

Tags: ios, json, core-data

i am working with coreData, I have two entities "Dept" and "employees" and "Dept" has one to many relationship with employee.

My app works fine offline, I can add Dept and inside that I can add employees.

For adding Dept I use NsFetchResultsController.

Here is how I add it

//AddDeptVC.m

```
-     (void)insertNewObject:(NSString *)DeptName
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [m_controller managedObjectContext];

                       //Creating a new instance of an managed object.
        Dept *dept = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@“Dept” inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        [dept  setDeptName: DeptName];



            //Commit the changes and save the context to store.Before this process all the changes are local.
            NSError *error;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                //Error handling
        }        
    }
```

Now I want to Sync this data to server, in return server will send me some departments and its employees which I need to add to my coreData db and update my table.

For this I created a Class called WebServiceClass, which will do push and pull, Pushing data to server works fine, but now when server returns me response, I did it this way

//This is written in webService class.

//WebServiceClass.m

```
Dept *dept = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@“Dept” inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        [dept  setDeptName: [responseDict objectForKey:@"deptName"];



            //Commit the changes and save the context to store.Before this process all the changes are local.
            NSError *error;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                //Error handling
        }
```

But this is not updating my table.

Here are my doubts.
1) Whether I am proceeding in right direction.
2) If yes then why my table is not updating.
3) is their any better approach than this.

Comment: Are you passing the managedObjectContext reference to the WebService Class ? the one you are referring to like this in it self.managedObjectContext ?

Comment: You are actually doing it right. The problem might be not passing the reference of managedObjectContext you are using in AddDeptVC.m  in the WebServiceClass.m or setting it to the [m_controller managedObjectContext]; like you did in AddDeptVC.m

Comment: I'm assuming that when you first instantiated your VC that you did a fetch (e.g. in viewDidLoad) to get the Dept objects from coredata and that you stashed those objects in an array. Are you updating that array somewhere so that your table has the data to update? Also, you might need to call [self.tableview reloadData] as well to force a reload (e.g. in viewDidAppear) once you've done that.

Comment: What merge policy are you using? When you attempt to save, is it returning an error?